# Converting Tkinter to ttk

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been using tkinter in order to code an application, but I've recently learned that there is a more modern ttk which I may use to style and theme widgets. However, after importing and using ttkthemes, it seems that it only affects ttk widgets and not the normal tk ones. Is there a way to convert the tk widgets into ttk. My current imports are

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
```

I guess I can just rewrite the tk portion that I have to be ttk widgets, but is there a simpler way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... it seems that it only affects ttk widgets and not the normal tk ones. Is there a way to convert the tk widgets into ttk.

No, there is not. Tk widgets and ttk widgets are separate things. As you've discovered, the ttk styles only affect ttk widgets.

> I guess I can just rewrite the tk portion that I have to be ttk widgets, but is there a simpler way to go about this?

Not really. Since you're doing a wildcard import of tkinter, you can do a wildcard import of ttk too, and the ttk widget classes will overwride the tkitner classes. However, the widgets are sufficiently different that rewriting is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

The name of the widgets are the same and there are some other cool widgets like Combobox, Treeview, etc.